# How to change boot timeout via C#?

Tags: c#, windows-7, timeout, boot

I need to change the boot timeout for choosing OS via C#.

I mean to the timeout that is usually changed via msconfig:

[image]

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use the Process class](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ProcessStart.aspx) to run [BCDEdit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28WS.10%29.aspx), specifically the /timeout switch

Comment: I get an exception of "System could not find the file specified"

Answer (score 0):

YOu can run the following command through c#.

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText= "/C bcdedit /timeout 0";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",strCmdText);
```

Comment: @sara, sorry the cmd is mean to be this : strCmdText= "/C bcdedit /timeout 0"; I left out the /C, but it now works 100%. Just remember to run it with elevated rights.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it via .NET then this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/WindowsVistaBCD.aspx is a good starting point - it shows how edit BCD programmatically...